# Parse json into multiple java pojos

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, gson

I am writing a Restful webservice which would receive data in the below format.

```
{
  "myOrder": {
    "submitDate": "2015-04-16T02:52:01.406-04:00",
    "supplier": "Amazon",
    "orderName": "Wifi Router",
    "submittedBy": "Gaurav Varma",
    "price": {
      "value": "2000",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "address": {
      "name": "My home",
      "address": "Unknow island",
      "city": "Mainland China",
      "state": "Xinjiang",
      "contact": {
        "firstName": "Gaurav",
        "lastName": "Varma",
        "phone": "000-000-0000",
        "email": "test@gv.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To read that data I am considering Jackson or GSON frameworks. The easiest way would be to use a Java POJO which has exactly the same structure as the json request. But for me the structure of Java POJOs is different. I have four different pojo as mentioned below :

```
Submitter.java
 - SubmittedBy
 - SubmitDate
Order.java
 - Supplier
 - OrderName
Price.java
 - Value
 - Currency
Address.java
 - Name
 - Address
 - City
 - State
Contact.java
 - FirstName
 - LastName
 - Phone
 - Email
```

Question : Is it a way to parse the json once into five different POJOs. May be some annotation based approach where we can map json attribute to respective pojo attribute? Any framework available for it?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you're using gson, you could create your own deserialiser. You'd need a outer container class which could be used to hold the other sub classes

Comment: @MadProgrammer While I try this, any reference example would be great

Comment: [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and maybe [Gson Deserialization Cookbook](http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution approach. Posting for other users. The complete implementation is on my blog - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2015/04/parse-json-into-multiple-java-pojos.html

So basically 3 points regarding solution approach:

1. We use Jackson annotation - @JsonIgnoreProperties. This would make
   sure only those fields in Pojo are mapped to JSON attributes. So we
   read the json twice, once mapping to Order.java and then to
   Submitter.java. Both gets the correspondingly mapped fields.
2. We use Jackson annotation - @JsonProperty. This lets us map the exact JSON attribute to a field in POJO. The annotation makes sure different named attributes in JSON and POJO are mapped.
3. Jackson doesn't provide any annotation to perform @JsonWrapped (The vice-versa @JsonUnwrapped is available for serialization). Hence, we map Price as an attribute in Order.java.

The main class looks like this :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonDeserializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // ObjectMapper provides functionality for data binding between
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String jsonString = "{\"submitDate\":\"2015-04-16\",\"submittedBy\":\"Gaurav Varma\",\"supplier\":\"Amazon\",\"orderName\":\"This is my order\"," 
                    + "\"price\": {\"value\": \"2000\",\"currency\": \"USD\"}"
                    + "}";
            System.out.println("JSON String: " + jsonString);

            // Deserialize JSON to java format and write to specific POJOs
            Submitter submitterObj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Submitter.class);
            Order orderObj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Order.class);
            Price priceObj = orderObj.getPrice();

            System.out.println("submitterObj: " + submitterObj);
            System.out.println("orderObj: " + orderObj);
            System.out.println("priceObj: " + priceObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [eclipse link moxy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy) for this. It uses JAXB style annotations for field to JSON/XML mapping.

Moxy is part of eclipse link.

**Wikipedia:**

> EclipseLink is the open source Eclipse Persistence Services Project
>   from the Eclipse Foundation. The software provides an extensible
>   framework that allows Java developers to interact with various data
>   services, including databases, web services, Object XML mapping (OXM),
>   and Enterprise Information Systems (EIS).

So in your code you would use it like;

Model A:

```
@XmlElement(name="completed_in")
public float getCompletedIn() {
    return completedIn;
}
```

Model B:

```
@XmlElement(name="created_at")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

@XmlElement(name="from_user")
public String getFromUser() {
    return fromUser;
}
```

Json:

```
{
  "completed_in":0.153,
  {
    "created_at":"Fri, 12 Aug 2011 01:14:57 +0000",
    "from_user":"stackfeed",
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Jackson on my project. You have the option of annotating your POJO fields with @JsonProperty or @JsonUnwrapped. You would use @JsonUnwrapped on Order, for example, and then Order would have two fields (supplier and orderName) that use @JsonProperty.

[See here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) for more details.

Comment: I found this approach as appropriate. Although needed more details. Hence, posting my own answer instead of accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jackson; I think you need a POJO to wrapp the Order and Address like

```
class FullOrder {
   Order order;
   Address address;

   public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
   }

   public void setOrder(Order order) {
       this.order = order;
   }

   public Address getAddress() {
       return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(Address address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
```

}

With this you can easily use Jackson

```
    String json; // your json here
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.readValue(json, FullOrder.class);
```

And that will parse the json into your pojo. Hope it helps you

---

The full structure

```
class Submitter {
    private Date submittedBy;
    private Date submitDate;

    public Date getSubmittedBy() {
     return SubmittedBy;
    }

    public void setSubmittedBy(Date submittedBy) {
     SubmittedBy = submittedBy;
    }

    public Date getSubmitDate() {
     return SubmitDate;
    }

    public void setSubmitDate(Date submitDate) {
     SubmitDate = submitDate;
    }

    }

    class Order {
    private String supplier;
    private String orderName;
    private Price price;
    private Submitter submitter;

    public Price getPrice() {
     return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Price price) {
     this.price = price;
    }

    public Submitter getSubmitter() {
     return submitter;
    }

    public void setSubmitter(Submitter submitter) {
     this.submitter = submitter;
    }

    public String getSupplier() {
     return Supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
     Supplier = supplier;
    }

    public String getOrderName() {
     return OrderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
     OrderName = orderName;
    }

}

class Price {
    private int value;
    private int currency;

    public int getValue() {
     return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
     this.value = value;
    }

    public int getCurrency() {
     return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(int currency) {
     this.currency = currency;
    }

}

class Address {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private Contact contact;

    public Contact getContact() {
     return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
     this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getName() {
     return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
     return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
     this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
     return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
     this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
     return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
     this.state = state;
    }

}

class Contact {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    long phone;
    String email;

    public String getFirstName() {
     return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
     this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
     return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
     this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
     return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
     this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
     return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
     this.email = email;
    }
}

class FullOrder {
   Order myOrder;
   Address address;

   public Order getMyOrder() {
        return order;
   }

   public void setMyOrder(Order order) {
       this.order = order;
   }

   public Address getAddress() {
       return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(Address address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
```

}

This is  structure of your json, you only need to copy it and use the Object mapper to parse the json to the pojo (FullOrder) that contains the other pojos and properties

```
    String json; // your json here
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.readValue(json, FullOrder.class);
```

Comment: in this approach, how do I decide what to put in Order.java and what in Submitter.java. You see, 2 each of those attributes in same hierarchy.

Comment: This is close. While it works for Price, Address and Contact, it doesn't work for Submitter and Order as they are not separate objects in the json. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes.. I forget it, you have to change your JSON to something similar to this

  "myOrder": {
    "submitter": {
    "submittedBy": "Gaurav Varma",
    "submitDate": "2015-04-16T02:52:01.406-04:00"
     },
    "supplier": "Amazon",
    "orderName": "Wifi Router",
    "price": {
      "value": "2000",
      "currency": "USD"
    }

But if you want to preserve the json structure you can write a custom StdDeserializer. WIth this approach you don't need to wrap the supplier data.

Comment: I had a typo in the full anwser but it correct it. If you use this approach make sure that the attributes names in json match with the attribute names in the classes.

Comment: We don't have to keep the same names as well. Jackson provides annotation based mapping for that. e.g. here I map json property submittedBy to java string submmiter -  @JsonProperty(value="submittedBy")
 String submitter;

Comment: Posted my answer. Check that once.

Comment: @rubenrodriguezfernandez Can you create one pojo that can store all the values, or do you must create a pojo class for each RootNode.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the composition design pattern and have an instance of each object in a wrapper class. Or you can try to parse the json into a map and write code to instantiate and set the variables as needed.

Comment: I considered using the map, but it will require quite a lot of hardcoding. Reading each the attribute name string as key and then getting the value.

Comment: not necessarily, it's a bit of a pain, but you can use reflection to instantiate a class and i believe that there are frameworks out there that help you set properties using reflection as well. it isn't pretty but it will work